# Erro ao instalar o git em instância EC2 com Cent OS 5

Tags: git, instalador, centos, amazon-aws

Estou com uma instância ec2 recem criada usando CentOS release 5.11 (Final).

Uma das primeiras coisas que tentei fazer foi instalar o git usando: `sudo yum install git` só que está apresentando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já dei o comando `sudo yum update` e seguidamente tentei instalar o git e apresentou o mesmo erro. Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: talvez nao esteja disponivel no repositorio, adiciona o repositorio EPEL,que voce vai conseguir.

Comment: @MarcosSouza, eu ainda cheguei tentar com o EPEL só que ainda continuou me retornando o mesmo erro :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema segui inicialmente esse [tutorial](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-git-on-centos-5/), só que com algumas modificações.

```
yum -y install zlib-devel openssl-devel cpio expat-devel gettext-devel
cd /usr/local/src
wget --no-check-certificate https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/git-core/git-1.8.5.5.tar.gz
tar xvzf git-1.8.5.5.tar.gz 
cd git-1.8.5.5
./configure
make
make install
```

OBS: Após rodar o comando configure, tive que instalar algumas dependências que faltavam, com o gcc (`sudo yum install gcc`)

OBS²: Mais links para versões do código fonte do git pode-se encontrar [aqui](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-core/downloads?page=1)

*Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40557198/5636215).